# Using XSLT, how do I separate nodes based on their value?

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

I have a pretty flat XML structure that I need to reorder into categorised sections and, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it in XSLT (not that I'm by any means an expert.)

Basically, the original XML looks kinda like:

```
<things>
  <thing>
    <value>one</value>
    <type>a</type>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <value>two</value>
    <type>b</type>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <value>thee</value>
    <type>b</type>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <value>four</value>
    <type>a</type>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <value>five</value>
    <type>d</type>
  </thing>
</things>
```

And I need to output something like:

```
<data>
  <a-things>
    <a>one</a>
    <a>four</a>
  </a-things>
  <b-things>
    <b>two</b>
    <b>three</b>
  </b-things>
  <d-things>
    <d>five</d>
  </d-things>
</data>
```

Note that I can't output `<c-things>` if there aren't any `<c>` elements, but I do know ahead of time what the complete list of types is, and it's fairly short so handcoding templates for each type is definitely possible. It feels like I could probably hack something together using `<xsl:if>` and `<xsl:for-each>` but it also feels like there must be a more ... 'templatey' way to do it. Can anyone help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2, you can do this very elegantly. Say you have a template for formatting each thing before it is wrapped in an <a> element:

```
<xsl:template match="thing" mode="format-thing">
    <xsl:value-of select="value/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can apply that to each thing of some `$type` to build the <a-things> elements via a function:

```
<xsl:function name="my:things-group" as="element()">
    <xsl:param name="type" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="things" as="element(thing)*"/>

    <xsl:element name="{ concat($type, '-things') }">
        <xsl:for-each select="$things[type/text() eq $type]">
            <xsl:element name="{ $type }">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="format-thing"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:function>
```

Then you can call that function for each unique type (a, b, d in your sample input) to build the entire output and you're done:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <xsl:sequence select="
            for $type in distinct-values(things/thing/type/text())
            return my:things-group($type, /things/thing)
            "/>
    </data>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4):

As you are using Saxon, use the native XSLT 2.0 grouping.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="things">
        <data>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="thing" group-by="type">
                <xsl:element name="{concat(current-grouping-key(),'-things')}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 1.0 you can group with keys. This approach is called *Muenchian Grouping*.

The xsl:key defines an index containing `thing` elements, grouped by the string value of their `type` element. Function `key()` returns all nodes from the key with the specified value.

The outer xsl:for-each selects the `thing` elements that are the first returned by `key()` for their value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="thing" match="thing" use="type" />

    <xsl:template match="things">
        <data>
            <xsl:for-each select="thing[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('thing',type)[1])]">
                <xsl:element name="{concat(type,'-things')}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('thing',type)">
                        <xsl:element name="{type}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The generic solution is to use an XSL key:

```
<xsl:key name="kThingByType" match="thing" use="type" />

<xsl:template match="things">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="thing" mode="group">
      <xsl:sort select="type" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thing" mode="group">
  <xsl:variable name="wholeGroup" select="key('kThingByType', type)" />
  <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($wholeGroup[1])">
    <xsl:element name="{type}-thing">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$wholeGroup/value" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The above yields:

```
<things>
  <a-thing>
    <value>one</value>
    <value>four</value>
  </a-thing>
  <b-thing>
    <value>two</value>
    <value>thee</value>
  </b-thing>
  <d-thing>
    <value>five</value>
  </d-thing>
</things>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, asking the question made it obvious...

My solution does use an `<xsl:if>`, but I can't see how it couldn't now I think about it. My solution looks basically like:

```
<xsl:if test="/things/thing/type = 'a'">
  <a-things>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/things/thing[type='a']" mode="a" />
  </a-things>
</if>

<xsl:template match="/things/thing[type='a']" mode="a">
    <a><xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

And repeat for the other types. I've coded it up, and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a-things>
    <xsl:for-each select="thing[type = 'a']">
        <a><xsl:value-of select="./value" /></a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</a-things>
```

If you want to get really snazzy, replace the `<a-things>` and the predicate with parameters and use attribute value templates:

```
<xsl:param name="type" />
<xsl:element name="{$type}-things">
    <xsl:for-each select="thing[type = $type]">
        <xsl:element name="{$type}"><xsl:value-of select="./value" /></xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

And using grouping, you can do it without the if:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="things">
    <data>
      <xsl:for-each select="thing[not(type=preceding-sibling::thing/type)]">
        <xsl:variable name="type"><xsl:value-of select="type" /></xsl:variable>
          <xsl:element name="concat($type, '-things')">
            <xsl:for-each select="../thing[type=$type]">
              <xsl:element name="$type">
                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```